# Python KafkaConsumer redirect json output (reply) to file

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

I am consuming Kafka messages using Kafkaconsumer in Python.

The reply I am getting from Kafka is in json format. I want to know how to create a json file using the reply I am getting from Kafka.

Here is my for loop to loop through the messages

```
Consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, groupid, Bootstrap server....)

For message in Consumer
   message =message.value
    # Here I want to create a new file
```

I want the file called Reply.json and write the message in the file.

Comment: Dear Onecricketeer, after consuming the message,  I see single quote in json file reply instead of double quote. Will you be able to help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is only an implementation detail. Open a file and write

```
with open('Reply.json', 'a'):
    for r in consumer:
        f.write(str(r.value))
        f.write('\n')
```

Note that this is an infinite loop, and your file may therefore become really large (your computer may crash if it runs out of disk space)

Comment: I tried this option and got this error write() argument must be str not dict

Comment: Convert the value to a string, then. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. Appriciate your quick help.